# How to check if an item is in a generator in Python with less Time Complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-itertools

```
gen = (i for i in range(1000))
print(555 in gen) #True
```

We can check if an element exists in a generator using the `in` operator.

1. What is the time complexity?
2. What is the best approach to reduce time complexity while searching for an element in a generator?

Comment: Binary search for instance. Or change the data structure like a dict which has faster lookup times, if that helps you.

Comment: For a linear structure that doesn't follow a pattern, membership lookups will be O(n). You can't get around that. In the worst case, the item you want will be last (or not present at all), and you'll need to check all of the generator to realize that. The only imprevement in this exact case would be to call `in` on the `range` directly since `range`'s membership lookup are O(1).

Comment: Is this a reduced, hypothetical or homework question? Are you trying to solve a specific problem in which you could e.g. avoid creating the generator in the first place? Given an arbitrary generator, there is no better approach to search for an element in the generator's values.

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to check if an element exists in the `permutations` generator of `itertools`

Comment: Are you looking if "an element is a permutation of <values>" or if "an element is inside `itertools.permutations(<values>)`"?

Comment: @whitehat The output produced by `permutations` would follow a pattern, so it should be possible to come up with a formula to calculate the index (although it would likely be complex). I would think though that due to the nature of `permutations`, you should be able to tell whether or not an element exists (although not necessarily the index) just by looking at the input list. `permutations` will produce all permutations of a list, so if the thing you're searching for is a permutation of the list, it will exist.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am looking for if "an element is a permutation of <values>"; and chose to use `permutations` from `itertools` which is returning a generator; So came here to check if the time complexity can be reduced? Maybe I should post a different question?

Comment: I don't think you need to use itertools at all for that particular task. if A is a permutation of B, then sorted(A) == sorted(B).

Comment: @whitehat You should ask a question specific to the permutation use-case, because it can likely be done *O(1)* with some smarts.

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce time complexity by using a set:

```
gen = {i for i in range(1000)}
print(555 in gen) #True
```

Sets are unordered, but hashed for faster lookups. Hope that helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: Although if you're feeding in a generator, you need to iterate the entire generator to put it in the set, so this is only preferable if you need to do multiple lookups on a single set of permutations.

Comment: Oh yes, this was intended to speed up lookups. If you are doing just 1 lookup you probably wouldn't form a set, but rarely are people concerned with the speed of just one lookup that takes milliseconds...

Comment: range objects themselves already support *O(1)* lookups.  Building a set from a range actually degrades this to *O(n)* (due to iterating the range).

Comment: Typically it isn't the building of the data structure that is considered in search time. If you are just doing one search this is all irrelevant.

Comment: My point was that you may as well use `555 in range(1000)` directly, the set adds nothing here.  And naming a set instance `gen` is misleading.

Comment: Yes, I understood your point :) I mean, really, if you are only going to use this `range`, just do `0 <= 555 < 1000`!